# How to know whether an Image is shown or not

Tags: uwp

In my UWP application, I need to show some Images in a scrollviewer, like below codes.
But sometimes some of the Image will not show, just a white blank there.

I want to know why this will happen?
And how to solve it?

E.g. how to detect that the Image is not shown via code? And how then re-load the image url?
Thanks!

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="1835" Height="556"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                          Margin="85,232,0,292">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/25_bailuobuzhusunshuiyatang.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/26_jiachangpaiguyumitang.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/27_caoguxiaren.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/28_xihuluchaoroupian.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/29_qingdouchaoxuecai.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/30_lancairoumozhengdoufu.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/31_xiaochaoxianniudu.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/32_yeshanjiaozhengcaoyu.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/33_qincaichaoxianggu.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/34_suanmiaochaolachang.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/35_shangtangbocai.jpg"/>
            <Image Source="https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/36_yumiwosunchaoxiaren.jpg"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try [HN.Controls.ImageEx](https://github.com/h82258652/HN.Controls.ImageEx). It's a more powerful image control than Microsoft's `Image` and `ImageEx`.

You can define the failed template, and set rerty times and interval, on order to get your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set for each image an instance of the class  [Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage?view=winrt-18362#events) to the image source and you can subscribe to the event **BitmapImage.ImageFailed**.

```
private void image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("https://audiores.lenovo.com.cn/audiores/skill/cook/food/25_bailuobuzhusunshuiyatang.jpg");
    bitmapImage.ImageFailed += BitmapImage_ImageFailed;

    if (sender is Image image)
    {
         image.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}

private void BitmapImage_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = sender as BitmapImage;
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/fallback.png");
}
```